# How can gets() be a member of the String class?

Tags: ruby

It was my understanding that there weren't any functions per se, but that everything was a method and that anything whose class you don't have to name explicitly is really a method of the `Kernel`.

I thought methods are objects because that method `gets` has a method `chomp` as in `myStr = gets.chomp`. [Ruby-doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html) tells that `chomp` is a `String` method. In fact, `gets.class` tells that `gets` is a `String` object. What is going on here? How can a `method` be a `String` object? From what mechanism does this behavior result, and where can I learn more about it?

Comment: Dave, you killed my flow. My precious creative fluff has been ruthlessly destroyed. All in the name of white space.

Comment: Sorry, Luke, but I think Dave was right to take his machete to your question. :-)  If it's not clear from the answers,  by "`gets` is a `String` object", I think you mean "the value returned by `gets` is a `String` object".

Comment: You're right not to change the question. I was just pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `gets` is a method call, and returned value is of type `String`. The string has method [`chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp), so you could nicely chain them as you mentioned:

```
myStr = gets.chomp
```

This is the same like:

```
myStr = gets().chomp()
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to obtain a method as an object, try:

```
chomp = "Hello".method(:chomp)
=> #<Method: String#chomp>
chomp.call # this is how you can "call" the method
```

Check the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-method) for more!

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ahh, so methods are objects just as I expected! my investigation method was just poor :)....... I have another question for you. In the documentation, when they refer to a methods 'receiver' are they talking about the particular object calling the method? If that is the case, are method objects  created only when you call them?

Comment: @LukeP The "receiver" is the object *receiving* the message, i.e., the object you're calling the method on. "Method objects" are created when you ask for them via the `method` method, otherwise they're just methods that *belong* to an object.

Comment: @LukeP - I like your hanger for knowledge! Answering first question - In Ruby we talk about concept of *sending messages* to objects. So, by `"Hello".chomp`, you are sending a message, to object "Hello" (which becomes a receiver). To prove this, you can try doing something like `"Hello".send(:chomp)`, which is exactly the same as `"Hello".chomp`.

Comment: Try to be more precise in your explanation. `gets` is a method, not a "method call". You should also give the module on which `gets` is defined (`Kernel`).

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing the environment/**receiver** of a method call and the **return value** of a method call. In general, they are not the same. `gets` is primarily defined on `Kernel`, and its return value is a `String` instance. `chomp` is defined on `String` and its return value is a `String`. `gets` being defined on `IO` is just a secondary thing for convenience.

Comment: Good explanation, but I'd change "primarily" to "here", or some-such.  In IRB we find: `method(:gets).owner #=> Kernel`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I mistook the other definition of `gets`. It was on `IO`, not on `String`. I had just believed what the OP wrote without verifying it. I don't understand why you wrote I should write "here". Can you add to it?

Comment: I just meant the OP was using `Kernel#gets` (but may not have known where it was defined). Maybe "the OP is using `gets` defined on `Kernel`". Btw, I didn't think "thing" was in your Ruby vocabulary. :-)